# Issues transferring Azure Run-As scripts to Managed Identity

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, ssas-tabular, azure-runbook

Due to the transition from ‘Run As’ accounts to Managed Identities in Azure Automation accounts, I have been following the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/migrate-run-as-accounts-managed-identity?tabs=run-as-account to alter the many PowerShell runbooks we use to kick off automated refreshes for SQL Server Analysis Services tabular models.

I have successfully set up a managed identity that has a role assignment giving it the necessary permissions. I have associated the identity to the automation account.

An example of the original refresh code looks like this:

```
=# Store connection data

$TenantId = "##################################"

$Credential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name 'TestRefresh2022'

$Server = "asazure://southcentralus.asazure.windows.net/*********"

$DatabaseName = "******"

$RolloutEnvironment = "southcentralus.asazure.windows.net"

 

# Log in to Azure Analysis Services using the Azure AD Service Principal

Add-AzureAnalysisServicesAccount -Credential $Credential -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -RolloutEnvironment $RolloutEnvironment

 

# Perform a Process Full on the Azure Analysis Services database

Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -Server $Server -RefreshType "Full"
```

The new code looks like this:

```
$TenantId = "#########################"

$Server = "asazure://southcentralus.asazure.windows.net/*********"

$DatabaseName = "*********"

$RolloutEnvironment = "southcentralus.asazure.windows.net"

 

$subscription = "*************"

$identity = "*************"

 

$null = Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process # Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook

 

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId $identity).context  # Connect to Azure with user-assigned managed identity

 

$connectionResult = Get-AzContext -ListAvailable | Where{$_.Name -match ‘*********’} | Set-AzContext -DefaultProfile $AzureContext

 

--Perform a Process Full on the Azure Analysis Services database

Invoke-ProcessASDatabase -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -Server $Server -RefreshType "Full"
```

When run, I receive the following message:

Completed.

Authentication failed: User ID and Password are required when user interface is not available.

Am I missing something in the code itself, or have I missed a step with the identity set-up?